# Why does my brakes not compress all the way until I slow to 40Kph

Tags: brakes, volvo

I have a 2003 Volvo S40 and it seems to have a strange brake issue that stops the brakes from compressing all the way until I slow to 40Kph. Once I do, I feel the brake pedal sink in and the brakes grab hold much more than they were before I slowed to 40.

What could be the cause? I have replaced all 4 pads and rotors (I had to, not because of this) and the issue remains, could it be the calipers? Vacuum? etc?

Please let me know

Comment: Is this an automatic transmission? If so, it might be shifting down a gear at 40 kph, in which case a leak in the brake booster vacuum line is a distinct possibility